# Variable storing body classList is wrongly updated during JQuery Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently creating a script to handle Ajax page transitions using JQuery's Ajax request function. Inside the `success` callback of the Ajax function, I need to be able to access the current page's `body` `classList`, and the `classList` of the `body` in the callback's returned `data`. As this script is transitioning between pages of my (Wordpress) site, I need to update the body classes during the Ajax `success` function.

Here is a very oversimplified version of my code to give you a general idea of what I'm doing:

```
function loadPageData(event, elem, eventType) {

    let _this = elem;

    // use this to determine where the transition comes from (i.e. to differentiate between home->single-casestudy and single-casestudy->single-casestudy etc...)
    let cameFromBodyClasses = elem.closest('body').classList;

    console.info('console test 1:', cameFromBodyClasses, cameFromBodyClasses.contains('home'));

    // Prevent the default behavior of clicking these links
    event.preventDefault();

    let th = eventType === 'menuLinkClick' ? $(_this) : $('.menu-main-container ul li.current-menu-item');
    let url = eventType === 'menuLinkClick' ? th.attr('href') : window.location.href;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {

            console.info('console test 2:', cameFromBodyClasses, cameFromBodyClasses.contains('home'));

            let htmlObject = document.createElement('html');
            htmlObject.innerHTML = data;

            $(document).find('body').attr('class', $(htmlObject).find('body').attr('class'));

            let newBody = $(htmlObject).find('body');

            // this console.info is now different to the previous two...
            console.info('console test 3:', cameFromBodyClasses, cameFromBodyClasses.contains('home'));

            // the below if statement is being passed because cameFromBodyClasses.contains('home') is false at this point (but it shouldn't be)
            if (cameFromBodyClasses.contains('home') && newBody.hasClass('single-casestudy')) {

                // if coming from 'home' page and going to 'single-casestudy' page

                    // do unique transition animation here

            }
        }
    });
}


$(document).on('click', 'a[data-ajax="true"]', function (e) {

    loadPageData(e, this, 'menuLinkClick');

}
```

**The Problem**

As you can see from the simplified code, I have 3 times in which I `console.info` the `cameFromBodyClasses` variable to check its value.

When navigating from the homepage to a single case study page, the first and second `console.info` calls show that the variable `cameFromBodyClasses` contains the `classList` of the homepage `body` tag as it should (because we have come from the homepage). The 3rd `console.info` call, however, is different and prints the `body` `classList` of the page I am navigating to (the single case study page), but it should still be printing the homepage's `body` `classList`, as the variable has not been altered in any way between the two `console.info` calls.

**So...**

How can I store the `body` `classList` of the page the user is navigating away from and prevent it from ever being updated/changed at any point during the Ajax call?

I assume it has something to do with the fact that I am creating a new `html` element and updating its `body` `classList` before the 3rd `console.info`, but I still do not understand why this would change the value of the `cameFromBodyClasses` variable as it is only set at one point during the function (and before the ajax call)

Comment: The `cameFromBodyClasses` is pointing to the classList on the body.  So when you change `$(document).find('body').attr('class', $(htmlObject).find('body').attr('class'));`, changing the classes on the body, the classList changes.  So yes, you will see the changes.  If you do not want to see the changes, you will have to duplicate the classList into a different array.

Comment: Side note; don't do `$(document).find('body')`.  Just use `$(document.body)`.  `head` and `body` are already properties on the `document`.  There is no need to look them up.

Comment: @Taplar Ahhh okay awesome that makes so much sense, I simply changed the line `let cameFromBodyClasses = elem.closest('body').classList;` to `let cameFromBodyClasses = [...elem.closest('body').classList];` to turn it into an array and now use `.includes()` instead of `.contains()`. Feel free to write that up as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the variable `cameFromBodyClasses` points to the classList, which is a form of an array.  If the *contents* of the array changes, `cameFromBodyClasses` will also reflect the changes because it just points to the array, not a unique array from what it originally pointed to.

Consider the following...

```js
var x = [ 'a', 'b'];
var y = x;

console.log(x, y);

x.push('c');

console.log(x, y);

y = x.slice(0);

x.push('d');

console.log(x, y);
```

As you can see, x and y both point to the same array in memory.  However, the last push is not reflected in y.  This is because of the `slice()` performed, which caused `y` to point to a completely different array.  So pushing to x would not affect y at that point.